# What do numbers mean in SQL ORDER/GROUP BY statements?

Tags: sql

I don't understand this SQL sub-query completely and some doubts about it:

1. what is the purpose of Numbers after "Group By" and "Order By" Keyword i.e. **GROUP BY 1,2,3** or **ORDER BY 1,2**

SubQuery:

```
SELECT a.dep_month,
         a.dep_day_of_week,
   AVG(a.flight_distance) AS average_distance
FROM (
SELECT dep_month,
             dep_day_of_week,
             dep_date,
             SUM(distance) AS flight_distance
    FROM flights
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
) a

 GROUP BY 1,2
 ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `ORDER BY 1,2` means order by 1st and 2nd fileds (in the `select`) i.e. `ORDER BY a.dep_month, a.dep_day_of_week`

Comment: I think answers should mention that this syntax seems to be getting deprecated: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal

Comment: ORDER BY ordinal position has been deprecated since 1992... (SQL-92) I.e. don't use it. GROUP BY ordinal position - I don't know if it ever has been a part of ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `ORDER BY 1, 2` means *Order By 1st and 2nd fields in the select*, so

```
    SELECT a.dep_month,
           a.dep_day_of_week,
      ...
  ORDER BY 1,2;
```

is equal to

```
    SELECT a.dep_month,
           a.dep_day_of_week,
       ...
  ORDER BY a.dep_month, a.dep_day_of_week;
```

The syntax can be convenient if we have a *long and complex expression* in a field:

```
    SELECT bla-bla-bla-...-bla-bla,
           ...
  ORDER BY 1 -- No Copy + Paste of "bla-bla-bla-...-bla-bla"
```

a *better approach*, however, is to put an *alias*

```
    SELECT bla-bla-bla-...-bla-bla AS MyExpression,
           ...
  ORDER BY MyExpression -- More readable than 1
```

Comment: Yeah, I never really considered using ordinals for the case of a complex expression; adding a CTE creating an aliased column always seems like a better way to do this.

Comment: @underscore_d: When facing an *old* RDBMS (like Interbase 4.0) it's often (alas!) the only way...

Comment: Hm, that said, aliases created in the `select` can be used in the `order`, right? So an intermediate CTE doesn't even seem necessary. *edit*: just noticed your edit :P

Answer (score 1):

The SQL standard provides from referring to columns in `order by` and `group by` by their (1-based) *position*, rather than their *expression*.

Drawing from your example, these two queries are identical:

```
SELECT dep_month,
       dep_day_of_week,
       dep_date,
       SUM(distance) AS flight_distance
FROM flights
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3

SELECT dep_month,
       dep_day_of_week,
       dep_date,
       SUM(distance) AS flight_distance
FROM flights
GROUP BY dep_month, dep_day_of_week, dep_date
```

---

As an aside, it should be noted that the entire `group by` clause is redundant, since it is deterministic; given the select columns, the `group by` clause simply lists all non-aggregate columns, thus adding no programatic value whatsoever.

Comment: The **old** SQL Standard, you mean!

Comment: @underscore_d AFAIK all databases support positional references in group/order by clauses

Comment: And I know databases that don't. GROUP BY ordinal position wasn't in ANSI SQL-92 anyway. What about SQL-89? (ORDER BY ordinal position was in SQL-92, and then deprecated.)

Answer (score 0):

The numbers after `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` are the columns.

In the Below Query:

> SELECT dep_month,
>                dep_day_of_week,
>                dep_date,
>                SUM(distance) AS flight_distance
>       FROM flights
>       GROUP BY 1,2,

1 is dep_month
2 is dep_day_of_week
3 is dep_date

But if you are giving SELECT * from the table; Then 1,2,3...etc will be the column names in the table order.

3